# A criterion for embedding $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

A polynomial map $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^2$,
$t \mapsto f(t):=(f_1(t),f_2(t))$ is called an embedding of $\mathbb{C}$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ if $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to its image under $f$,
see [A. van den Essen](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2839040_Around_the_Abhyankar-Moh_Theorem), page 2.
(By a polynomial map we mean that $f_1(t),f_2(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$).

After Example 1 (also in page 2), A van den Essen presents a criterion from differential geometry: $f$ is an embedding if and only if $f'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{C}$ and the map $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^2$ is injective.

Now, replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{R}$ and call a polynomial map as above an embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (= $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to its image under $f$).

> Is the differential geometry criterion holds over $\mathbb{R}$?

Any hints are welcome!

**Edit:** **(1)** I do not see how [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449132/embedding-mathbbr-to-mathbbr2?rq=1) question or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227945/can-there-be-a-embedding-from-the-real-number-line-to-the-plane-such-it-is-both) question help in solving my question, although they are somewhat relevant (I am not sure if my question should be tagged also 'real analysis' or 'general topology').
**(2)** I guess that my question has a trivial positive answer? Namely, such a criterion is also valid over $\mathbb{R}$?

**Another Edit:** My question has a counterexample $\mathbb{R}[t^2,t+t^3] \subsetneq \mathbb{R}[t]$, but $f(t)= (t^2,t+t^3)$ satisfies the geometric conditions ($f'(t) \neq 0$ and $f$ is injective); please see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297555/abhyankar-moh-embedding-theorem-without-algebraic-closedness).
Therefore, I would like to ask:

> Is it possible to find an additional condition (in addition to the two geometric conditions $f'(t) \neq 0$ and $f$ is injective) which will guarantee that $\mathbb{R}[f_1(t),f_2(t)]=\mathbb{R}[t]$? (Perhaps the additional condition will involve the second derivative $f''(t)$?).

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is an injective immersion ($f'(t)\neq0$) that is not a topological embedding. See the figure in [An injective immersion that is not a topological embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067540/an-injective-immersion-that-is-not-a-topological-embedding). In my opinion, the author assumes $f$ is a polynomial. Then you can avoid this example.

Comment: @ChoF, thank you very much for your comment! Unfortunately, I still do not understand what is the answer to my question. If I understand correctly, the example in the link is $f(t)=(\sin{2t},\sin{t})$, which is not a polynomial map (so perhaps my question has a positive answer after all?).

Comment: If $f$ is polynomial, i.e., $f_1(t),f_2(t)\in\mathbb{R}[t]$, then the "if and only if" condition makes sense. Actually ($\Rightarrow$) holds always, but ($\Leftarrow$) may not. In case that $f$ is polynomial, ($\Leftarrow$) also holds, I think.

Comment: The extra condition you need to get an embedding is properness. Can you prove that a polynomial map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ is proper (preimage of compact is compact)?

Comment: Thank you very much both of you! @TedShifrin, please: (1) Do you claim that ChoF's last comment is correct?, and (2) A polynomial map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is always proper?

Comment: @ChoF: Sorry, I now read your first comment again and have noticed that I misread it before; when you wrote: ''In my opinion, the author assumes $f$ is a polynomial map" you referred to A. van den Essen, and I thought that you referred to J. Lee (since van den Essen explicitly wrote 'a polynomial map', so there is no doubt it is a polynomial map).

Comment: @TedShifrin, I 'guess' that both my questions to you (1) and (2) have positive answers. Here is a link to properness: http://planetmath.org/polynomialfunctionisapropermap; in the link the polynomial map is $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, but I think it is immediate to adjust that proof to a map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @user237522 As Ted Shifrin pointed out, it is well-known that "Let $f\colon M\to N$ be a proper injective immersion of differentiable manifolds $M$ and $N$. Then $f$ is an imbedding and $f(M)$ is a regular submanifold and a closed subset of $N$, and conversely." You can find the proof [here (p.8)](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~erin/topology/205C_midterm_1.pdf).

Comment: @ChoF, thanks again! So my question is a special case of the well-known theorem you now quoted?

Comment: This clarification for properness is very helpful.

Comment: @user237522 My previous comment on $f$ being proper was not correct. We only know that $f^{-1}(C)\subset f_1^{-1}(p_1(C))\cap f_2^{-1}(p_2(C))\subset\mathbb{R}$. We already know that $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed since the compact set $C$ is closed. Furthermore, $f_1^{-1}(p_1(C))\cap f_2^{-1}(p_2(C))$ is bounded so that $f^{-1}(C)$ is also bounded. Thus $f^{-1}(C)$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks again. You and Ted Shifrin helped me a lot.

Comment: @TedShifrin, please, can you explain to me in a few sentences why http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/apm/apm58/apm5834.pdf is NOT relevant to my question. Is it because here $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ (finite?), while there  $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ (What happens if in that paper we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by $\mathbb{R}$?). I really apologize if my comment is not reasonable; it is because I am not familiar with the algebraic geometry notions in that paper.

Comment: @user237522: Polynomial mappings in more than one variable are generally not proper (definitely not when we work over $\Bbb C$) because the zero-sets are algebraic varieties and hence often unbounded (*always* over $\Bbb C$).

Comment: @TedShifrin, thank you very much!

Comment: @TedShifrin, I am afraid that we were talking about different definitions: My definition is $\mathbb{R}[f_1(t),f_2(t)]=\mathbb{R}[t]$. In my definition there is a counterexample to my question: $f_1(t)=t^2$, $f_2(t)=t+t^3$ which satisfies the geometric criterion ($f'(t) \neq 0$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is injective), but does not satisfy the algebraic condition ($\mathbb{R}[t^2,t+t^3] \subsetneq \mathbb{R}[t]$). See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297555/abhyankar-moh-embedding-theorem-without-algebraic-closedness/297591?noredirect=1#comment740211_297591

Comment: @ChoF, can you please present your definition of an embedding? (You mentioned 'topological embedding'?). I guess that what you were claiming is that geometic embedding is quivalent to topological embedding. But I was interested in algebraic embedding.. Please see my above comment to Ted Shifrin (which is also a comment for you).

Comment: Please, did you mean the following definition: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/embedding+of+topological+spaces

Comment: @user237522 I mentioned that the iff criterion does not hold in the case of "topological embedding", and it may be possible to hold in the case of "polynomial (algebraic) embedding". But I cannot guarantee it. No proof.

Comment: @ChoF, thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Please, can you write the exact claim that you had in mind, concerning your definition of an embedding and 'my' algebraic definition.

Comment: I think van den Essen's algebraic notion is rather unusual and is, apparently, unrelated to the usual differential topology notion. I don't see how you're going to detect the algebra with topology. My claim was only regarding the usual "proper 1-1 immersion = embedding" theorem in differential topology.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thank you. Please, do you think that there is a reasonable additional condition to $f'(t)\neq 0$ and $f$ is injective, that will imply that $\mathbb{R}[f_1(t),f_2(t)]=\mathbb{R}[t]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write a brief answer here, rather than continuing in comments. The algebraic condition cannot be recovered by a differential topological criterion. Here's the proof.

I will write down a global diffeomorphism (which is definitely *not* algebraic) of $\Bbb R^2$ carrying the parametric curve $g(t)=(t^2,t)$ [for which the algebraic criterion holds, of course] to the parametric curve $f(t)=(t^2,t+t^3)$ [for which it fails]. To do this, let $\rho\colon\Bbb R\to [0,1]$ be a smooth function with $\rho(x) = 0$ for all $x\le -1/2$ and $\rho(1)=1$ for all $x\ge 0$. Define $F\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ by
$$F(x,y) = \big(x,y(1+\rho(x)x)\big).$$
You can check that $F$ is a diffeomorphism (it's easy enough to write down the global inverse function and see it's smooth). And $F(g(t)) = F(t^2,t) = \big(t^2,t(1+\rho(t^2)t^2)\big) = (t^2,t+t^3) = f(t)$, as promised.