# A criterion for embedding $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

The current question is motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698100/a-criterion-for-embedding-mathbbr-in-mathbbr2).

Call a polynomial map $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^2$,
$t \mapsto f(t):=(f_1(t),f_2(t))$ an embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ if $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to its image under $f$
(see [A. van den Essen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698100/a-criterion-for-embedding-mathbbr-in-mathbbr2), page 2, for fields).
By a polynomial map we mean that $f_1(t),f_2(t) \in \mathbb{Z}[t]$.

> Is the following claim true:
>   $f$ is an embedding if and only if $f'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the map $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ is injective.

Notice that if we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{C}$, then the claim (is true and) appears in A. van den Essen's paper, while if we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{R}$, then the claim (is true and) appears in the comments to my above mentioned question.

**Remarks:** **(1)** I guess that I should carefully check the arguments in the comments to my previous question and see if they are still valid if we work with $\mathbb{Z}$.

**(2)** I really apologize if it happens that my question is not reasonable. (Perhaps only working over fields make sense? So what if we take $\mathbb{Q}$? Or certain properties of $\mathbb{R}$ are necessary?).

Comment: What do you mean by isomorphic? Isomorphic as what?

Comment: Good question. I am not sure I know the answer. Isomorphic as rings will not be enough?

Comment: How is the image of $f$ supposed to be a ring? I'm afraid your remark (2) applies and this question is not reasonable.

Comment: Consider $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ with $f(t)=(t^2,t^3)$. Then $f$ is an embedding, but its derivative is not nonzero everywhere.

(here I consider the embedding as a topological embedding)

Comment: Thanks for both of you. What about $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Mihail, what I actually wanted is to obtain that $A[t]=A[f_1(t),f_2(t)]$, where $A$ is some ring $A \in \{\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}\}$. In the definition $f$ having an inverse on its image, perhaps (and perhaps not) working with sets is enough?

Comment: In other words, is Abhyankar-Moh theorem valid over any commutative integral domain? But I also liked the criterion with the derivatives.