# Proper polynomial mappings

Tags: general-topology, polynomials, compactness, several-complex-variables

One of the comments in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698100/a-criterion-for-embedding-mathbbr-in-mathbbr2) says:
"Polynomial mappings in more than one variable are generally not proper
(definitely not when we work over $\mathbb{C}$) because the zero-sets are algebraic varieties and hence often unbounded (always over $\mathbb{C}$)."

(Proper map means preimages of compact sets are compacts).

> (1) What happens over $\mathbb{R}$?
>
> (2) Can one please elaborate on cases where such mappings are proper?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider the difference between $f(a,b)  = a^2+b^2$ when defined as a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ vs. $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$, e.g.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: In the former case, fibres are circles in the plane (so compact) and a complex "circle" is unbounded, e.g. $(ni, n)$ is in the fibre of $0$ for all $n$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Is it just a special case?

Comment: Yes, $x^3 + y^3$ also has unbounded fibres over the reals but it shows how restricting to the reals sometimes does help.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.