# Why $\mathbb{C}[f_1(t),f_2(t)]=\mathbb{C}[t]$ iff $(f'_1(t),f'_2(t))\neq0$ and $t\mapsto (f_1(t),f_2(t))$ is injective?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
Let $f_1(t),f_2(t) \in k[t]$ and $f: k \to k^2$ defined by $f(t):=(f_1(t),f_2(t))$.

**First case** $k=\mathbb{C}$:
According to [A. van den Essen](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-18487-1_17) (page 2), the following claim holds:
$\mathbb{C}[f_1(t),f_2(t)]=\mathbb{C}[t]$ if and only if $f'(t)\neq (0,0)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is injective.

> **(1)** Can one please sketch a proof for this claim?

**Second case $k=\mathbb{R}$:** It is not true that if $f'(t)\neq (0,0)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is injective, then $\mathbb{R}[f_1(t),f_2(t)]=\mathbb{R}[t]$, as the following example shows: $f_1(t)=t^2$, $f_2(t)=t+t^3$.

> **(2)** Is there an additional differential geometry condition, call it $C$, such that: $\mathbb{R}[f_1(t),f_2(t)]=\mathbb{R}[t]$ if and only if $f'(t)\neq (0,0)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is injective, and $C$.

**Remarks**: **Concerning question (2):** (i) I am interested in a 'not too strong' additional condition, namely, not something like $f_1'(t)=1$.
(ii) Perhaps the additional condition $C$ will involve the second derivative $f''(t)$?
**Concerning both questions:** (iii) Please see the comments in
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698100/a-criterion-for-embedding-mathbbr-in-mathbbr2#comment5641411_2698100), especially, how [page 8, claim b](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~erin/topology/205C_midterm_1.pdf) is relevant to my question? (iv) Considering the fields of fractions $k(f_1(t),f_2(t))=k(t)$ instead of $k[f_1(t),f_2(t)]=k[t]$ seem also interesting.

**Edit:** [This paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0022404994900833/1-s2.0-0022404994900833-main.pdf?_tid=a89a49a7-108e-4542-8079-f4c6f64cbf79&acdnat=1523732364_eeb99603e6e67d25c4c0d989880fe950) is somewhat relevant.

Any comments and hints are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the relevant results that answer my first question:
[Lemma 1.1](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0022404994900833/1-s2.0-0022404994900833-main.pdf?_tid=a89a49a7-108e-4542-8079-f4c6f64cbf79&acdnat=1523732364_eeb99603e6e67d25c4c0d989880fe950) and [Theorem 2.1(2)](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-03/S0002-9939-97-03639-3/S0002-9939-97-03639-3.pdf).

One sees that $\mathbb{C}$ can be replaced by any algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, since Lemma 1.1 is valid over any
algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and Theorem 2.1(2) is valid over an arbitrary field.

Comment: The first link is dead.

Comment: @user26857, thank you. Unfortunately, I do not remember now what Lemma 1.1 says. If I will be able to recall it, then I will add it (and notify you).